# Power builder datawindows

Tags: powerbuilder

There are two datawindows in a window, header part and detail part. Detail part datawindow is multirow datawindow where it is not displaying after tried via .exe.

Long back its worked with adding 1st datawindow fields to 2nd datawindow and 2nd datawindow fields to 1st datawindow. But now it's not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Normally there is a key value from the parent which is used to retrieve the child rows.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using datashare between 2 datawindows. If the fields on both database does not match (column name + column order), it may not show the datawindow which is shared by the primary datawindow.